# Не работает Selector в ImageView

Tags: android

```
<item  
   android:drawable = "@drawable/numpad_button_bg_selected"  
   android:state_selected = "true" ></item> 
<item  
   android:drawable = "@drawable/numpad_button_bg_pressed"   
   android:state_pressed = "true" ></item> 
<item  
   android:drawable = "@drawable/numpad_button_bg_normal" ></item>
```

Смысл такой. Есть `imageView` с картинкой. `numpad_button_bg_normal`

Если нажал `numpad_button_bg_pressed`

Если отпустил `numpad_button_bg_selected`

`android:state_selected` не работает, кучу форумов прочитал и на `stack` тож перепробовал не работает.

Как быть ребята?

Comment: вы это как сделали, со стилями? и покажите сам `ImageView`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

У imageView нет метода isChecked() и тд. А значит нет такого функционала и состояния. Вам стоит написать свою кастомную вью.

```
public class CheckableImageView extends ImageView {
    private boolean m_bChecked = false;
    private boolean m_bNewDrawable = false;
    private int m_nDrawableChecked = R.drawable.numpad_button_bg_selected;
    private int m_nDrawableNoChecked = R.drawable.numpad_button_bg_normal;

    public CheckableImageView(Context context) {
        super(context);
        setChecked(m_bChecked);
    }

    public CheckableImageView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        setChecked(m_bChecked);
    }

    public CheckableImageView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
        setChecked(m_bChecked);
    }

    public boolean isChecked(){
        return m_bChecked;
    }

    public void setChecked(boolean isChecked){
        m_bChecked = isChecked;
        if(isChecked){
        this.setImageResource(m_nDrawableChecked);
            if(m_bNewDrawable){
            this.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.white));
            }
        } else {
            if(m_nDrawableNoChecked!=-1) {
                this.setImageResource(m_nDrawableNoChecked);
            } else {
                this.setImageDrawable(null);
            }
            if(m_bNewDrawable){
            this.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.white));
            }
        }
        this.invalidate();
    }

    public void setDrawable(int idDrawableOn, int idDrawableOff){
        m_nDrawableChecked = idDrawableOn;
        m_nDrawableNoChecked = idDrawableOff;
        m_bNewDrawable = true;
        setChecked(m_bChecked);
    }

    public void changeCheckState(){
        setChecked(!m_bChecked);
    }
}
```

Будьте внимательны, я в коде также указываю цвет фона!

Comment: не рабоает ваш код

Comment: @xTIGRx, если вы не разобрались, то это не означает, что он не работает. А можно конкретней, что именно не работает?

Comment: Ну картинка не сохраняется. А если нажать и держать то картинка поменятся, если отпустить то сбросится. А мне нужно было чтобы нажал на картинку а она поменяла на другую. Странно почему Андроид такое не делает. Вот представь в XML указываешь картинку до картинку после и картинку во время нажатия. удобно же. Чем в каждом коде указывать что после нажатия надо менять картинку

Comment: Вам надо сделать как кнопка меняет состояние во время клика или как чекбокс, что бы нажали, а картинка поменялась и осталась такойже или после того как убераете палец, чтобы в начальное состояние возвращалось?

Comment: Вы должны в обработчике нажатия вызвать метод changeCheckState(); у этого вью))

Comment: ...............Ок)

Answer (score 2):

Обично это делается таким образом

ImageView

```
<ImageView 
      android:contentDescription="@string/description_numpad_button"
      android:src="@drawable/numpad_button" />
```

теперь создаем файл `numpad_button.xml` в папке `drawable` так:

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item 
       android:state_focused="true" 
       android:state_pressed="true" 
       android:drawable="@drawable/numpad_button_bg_selected"/>
    <item 
       android:state_focused="false" 
       android:state_pressed="true" 
       android:drawable="@drawable/numpad_button_bg_pressed"/>
    <item 
       android:state_focused="true"
       android:drawable="@drawable/numpad_button_bg_selected"/>
    <item 
       android:state_focused="false" 
       android:state_pressed="false" 
       android:drawable="@drawable/numpad_button_bg_normal"/>
</selector>
```

попробуйте

Comment: style="@style/numpad_button" нет такого файла

Comment: извините это можно убрать

Comment: Убрал, но все равно будто правда у ImageView нет checked.

работает также как если бы я выставил только android:state_focused=true. Тоесть картинка не меняется после того как я нажму на него. Он меняется пока нажата кнопка. если отпустит то все вернется

Comment: пробовали свойства `android:clickable="true"` ставить? на `ImageView`

Comment: Да, все тоже самое. пишу под API 23

Comment: Вы советуете ему селектор для кнопки, а человеку нужен селектор для CheckBox, но примененный к ImageView

Comment: @ВиталийОбидейко спасибо за заметку, но в вопросе не было слово про `CheckBox` и вот я посоветовал что есть